# Comparing two generators in Python

Tags: python

I am wondering about the use of `==` when comparing two generators

For example:

```
x = ['1','2','3','4','5']

gen_1 = (int(ele) for ele in x)
gen_2 = (int(ele) for ele in x)
```

**gen_1** and **gen_2** are the same for all practical purposes, and yet when I compare them:

```
>>> gen_1 == gen_2
False
```

My guess here is that `==` here is treated like `is` normally is, and since **gen_1** and **gen_2** are located in different places in memory:

```
>>> gen_1
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x01E8BAA8>
>>> gen_2
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x01EEE4B8>
```

their comparison evaluates to `False`. Am I right on this guess? And any other insight is welcome.

And btw, I do know how to compare two generators:

```
>>> all(a == b for a,b in zip(gen_1, gen_2))
True
```

or even

```
>>> list(gen_1) == list(gen_2)
True
```

But if there is a better way, I'd love to know.

Comment: Think of a generator expression as being like a function, not like a list.

Comment: once you compare generators you exhaust them and then they become empty

Comment: @LukaRahne Not exact. Generators can be infinite. `==` would just compare object identity. If you iterate over the generators, would could get an infinite loop in the general case.

Comment: @Gulzar comment was about `all(a == b for a,b in zip(gen_1, gen_2))`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are right with your guess – the fallback for comparison of types that don't define `==` is comparison based on object identity.

A better way to compare the values they generate would be

```
from itertools import zip_longest, tee
sentinel = object()
all(a == b for a, b in zip_longest(gen_1, gen_2, fillvalue=sentinel))
```

*(For Python 2.x use `izip_longest` instead of `zip_longest`)*

This can actually short-circuit without necessarily having to look at all values.  As pointed out by larsmans in the comments, we can't use `zip()` here since it might give wrong results if the generators produce a different number of elements – `zip()` will stop on the shortest iterator.  We use a newly created `object` instance as fill value for `zip_longest()`, since `object` instances compare unequal to any sane value that could appear in one of the generators (including other object instances).

Note that there is no way to compare generators without changing their state.  You could store the items that were consumed if you need them later on:

```
gen_1, gen_1_teed = tee(gen_1)
gen_2, gen_2_teed = tee(gen_2)
all(a == b for a, b in zip_longest(gen_1, gen_2, fillvalue=sentinel))
```

This will give leave the state of `gen_1` and `gen_2` essentially unchanged.  All values consumed by `all()` are stored inside the `tee` object.

At that point, you might ask yourself if it is really worth it to use lazy generators for the application at hand -- it might be better to simply convert them to lists and work with the lists instead.

Comment: `izip` has the same problem as `zip`: it fails when the generators do not generate an equal number of items.

Comment: Just a note for the use of `tee()`: Both the created iterators should be equal. There is no reason to prefer one over the other. Is not it more logical to keep the iterator assigned to the original name unconsumed for later processing? `gen_1, gen_1_to_compare = tee(gen_1)` ,,,or do you use the new name `gen_1_teed` to make clear that the iterator was changed (possible overhead, values in memory...)?

Comment: @pabouk I don't have any strong opionion on the naming here – in a real-world use case, I'd adapt the names to the use case. Also note that I wrote this answer a decade ago, so I don't quite remember what I thought at the time. :)

Comment: "`sentinel` is guaranteed to compare unequal to everything else" -- this is not true. A class can implement `__eq__` so that its elements will compare equal (`==`) to a newly created `object()`.

Comment: @amka66 I guess the whole paragraph isn't quite accurate anymore, since comparison works differently in Python 3. We don't have `__cmp__()` anymore, and the reason that `object` instances compare unequal to everything else is that `some_object.__eq__(something_else)` always returns `NotImplemented`, which in turn results in `something_else.__eq__(some_object)` being evaluated. I don't think all these details are helpful in this answer, so I'll update it to be more vague.

Comment: @SvenMarnach `some_object.__eq__(something_else)` does not always raise `NotImplemented` -- when `some_object` is an instance of a class that overrides the equality operator. Unless python3 does something to ensure symmetry (e.g., invoke both objects' `__eq__` method), custom classes may still compare equal to `sentinel`. A better solution may be `all((a is not sentinel and b is not sentinel and a == b) for a, b in zip_longest(iterable1, iterable2, fillvalue=sentinel))`

Comment: @amka66 By `some_object`, I meant an instance of `object`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I know -- any class is a subclass of object and hence any instance whatsoever is an instance of `object`.

Comment: @amka66 More specifically, I meant that `sentinel.__eq__(something_else)` always returns `NotImplemented`.

Comment: And you are right that custom classes can override to `__eq__()` to compare equal to sentinel, but that's on them, and it's wrong to make the code here more complicated to cater for that.

Comment: @amka66 I think we have some crossed wires here. Yes, it's possible for custom classes to be implemented in a way to compare equal to `sentinel`, which would kind of break the code in this answer. It doesn't matter which iterator is shorter. If `sentinel.__eq__(x)` returns `NotImplemented`, the interpreter will invoke `x.__eq__(sentinel)` instead, so it's possible either way. However, that would be a bug in the implementation of `__eq__` for the custom class, and we shouldn't make our code more complicated an harder to read to cater for very unlikely bugs elsewhere.

Answer (score 12):

Because generators generate their values on-demand, there isn't any way to "compare" them without actually *consuming* them. And if your generators generate an infinite sequence of values, such an equality test as you propose would be useless.

Answer (score 7):

`==` is indeed the same as `is` on two generators, because that's the only check that can be made without changing their state and thus losing elements.

```
list(gen_1) == list(gen_2)
```

is the reliable and general way of comparing two finite generators (but obviously consumes both); your `zip`-based solution fails when they do not generate an equal numbers of elements:

```
>>> list(zip([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3]))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
>>> all(a == b for a, b in zip([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3]))
True
```

The `list`-based solution still fails when either generator generates an infinite number of elements. You can devise a workaround for that, but when both generators are infinite, you can only devise a [semi-algorithm](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semi-algorithm) for non-equality.

Answer (score 5):

In order to do an item-wise comparison of two generators as with lists and other containers, Python would have to consume them both entirely (well, the shorter one, anyway). I think it's good that you must do this explicitly, especially since one or the other may be infinite.