# Check where two generators are different

Tags: python, functional-programming, generator

Suppose I have two generators, for simplicity:

```
it1 = iter([1,2,3,4])
it2 = iter([1,2,10,20])
```

what is the best way to know where is the first difference (position 2) or if they are equal? I would like to avoid explicit loop:

```
for pos, v1, v2 in enumerate(izip(it1, it2)):
   if v1 != v2: return pos
return None
```

and use functional programming:

```
try:
  return next(pos for pos, (v1, v2) in enumerate(izip(it1, it2)) if v1 != v2)
except StopIteration:
  return None
```

The point is that the solution I am using is ugly, more verbose than the explicit loop, ...

can you do better?

Comment: I would argue that the loop is the cleanest way to do this...

Comment: @mgilson: you are out of topic.

Comment: *"I would like to avoid explicit loop"* - why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your second example by giving a default value to `next`:

```
return next((pos for pos, (v1, v2) in enumerate(izip(it1, it2)) if v1 != v2), None)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

> `next(iterator[, default])`
>
> Retrieve the next item from the `iterator` by calling its `__next__()` method. **If `default` is given, it is returned if the iterator is
>   exhausted**, otherwise `StopIteration` is raised.

Comment: this is much better. I didn't know the second argument of `next`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative answer you can use `numpy.where` instead loop over your arrays and use `enumerate` :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def test(a,b):
...    try :
...         return np.where(a!=b)[0][0]
...    except IndexError:
...         return None
... 
>>> test(it1,it2)
>>> it1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> it2 = np.array([1,2,0,4])
>>> test(it1,it2)
2
```

Or with `next` :

```
>>> it1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,6])
>>> it2 = np.array([1,2,3,0,6])
>>> next(iter(np.where(it1!=it2)[0]),None)
3
```

Also for `generators` you can use [`numpy.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) to convert your generator to a numpy array!

some benchmarks :

```
:~$ python -m timeit "from itertools import izip;it1=[1,2,3,4];it2=[1,2,10,20];next((pos for pos, (v1, v2) in enumerate(izip(it1, it2)) if v1 != v2), None)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.77 usec per loop
:~$ python -m timeit "import numpy as np;it1=[1,2,3,4];it2=[1,2,10,20];next(iter(np.where(it1!=it2)[0]),None)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.02 usec per loop
```

Comment: it doesn't seems to be very efficient. I guess internally you are looping one time to check if the arrays are equal, and a second time to check where they are different.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra oh, yes! the checking for equality was remained from my older try! thanks for reminding!

Comment: it's not clear to me if numpy transforms iterators into `np.array`s or if it uses them as they are.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra no you need to convert your generators to numpy arrays! checkout the edit! any way this is answer than using `enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with builtin [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) but probably [python3 filterfalse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) might be even nicer.

```
filter(lambda x: x if len(set(x)) else None, zip(it1, it2))
>>> [(3, 10), (4, 20)]
```

However, we don't get index of differences but just different items in such way.

So I've been thinking some more and check for [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983547/comparing-two-generators-in-python) but then actually, OP wants index not a result. So, revised

```
filter(lambda x:x[0] if len(set(x[1])) > 1 else None, enumerate(zip(it1,it2)))
>>> [(2, (3, 10)), (3, (4, 20))]
```

Of course this doesn't even come close to above answers so I wouldn't recommend that in production code. Only benefit? No imports. Here are my timeit results:

```
python -m timeit "import numpy as np;it1=[1,2,3,4];it2=[1,2,10,20];next(iter(np.where(it1!=it2)[0]),None)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.02 usec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 13.1 usec per loop

python -m timeit "from itertools import izip;it1=[1,2,3,4];it2=[1,2,10,20];next((pos for pos, (v1, v2) in enumerate(izip(it1, it2)) if v1 != v2), None)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.6 usec per loop

python -m timeit "it1=[1,2,3,4];it2=[1,2,10,20];filter(lambda x:x[0] if len(set(x[1])) > 1 else None, enumerate(zip(it1,it2)))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.1 usec per loop
```

Comment: your solutions do not stop at the first difference. I don't need all the different elements. I just want the first.