# compare two defaultdict(list) with logical conditions

Tags: python-3.x, defaultdict

two defaultdict(list)

#### ids

```
3:42259955 [{'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '224', 'base': 'A', 'count': '1', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '1', 'percent_bias': 0.0, 'vaf': 0.0, 'mutation': 'snv', 'group': '5555', 'timepoint': 'D0', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '224', 'base': 'C', 'count': '0', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '0', 'percent_bias': '0', 'vaf': '0', 'mutation': 'snv', 'group': '5555', 'timepoint': 'D0', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '224', 'base': 'G', 'count': '223', 'positive_strand': '121', 'negative_strand': '102', 'percent_bias': 0.54, 'vaf': 1.0, 'mutation': 'no-mutation', 'group': '5555', 'timepoint': 'D0', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '224', 'base': 'T', 'count': '0', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '0', 'percent_bias': '0', 'vaf': '0', 'mutation': 'snv', 'group': '5555', 'timepoint': 'D0', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '224', 'base': 'N', 'count': '0', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '0', 'percent_bias': '0', 'vaf': '0', 'mutation': 'snv', 'group': '5555', 'timepoint': 'D0', 'st': '42259955'}]
```

#### V1

```
3:42259955 [{'group': '5555', 'timepoint': 'D0', 'chrm': '3', 'st': '42259955', 'en': '42259956', 'var': 'C'}, {'group': '5555', 'timepoint': 'C1', 'chrm': '3', 'st': '42259955', 'en': '42259956', 'var': 'C'}, {'group': '5555', 'timepoint': 'C3', 'chrm': '3', 'st': '42259955', 'en': '42259956', 'var': 'C'}, {'group': '5555', 'timepoint': 'C4', 'chrm': '3', 'st': '42259955', 'en': '42259956', 'var': 'C'}]
```

What i intend to do is

compare two default dict lists
first check is key matches
check if the ref and base are same in ids if yes store the depth info this will be constant
    which is this entry
    {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '224', 'base': 'G', 'count': '223', 'positive_strand': '121', 'negative_strand': '102', 'percent_bias': 0.54, 'vaf': 1.0, 'mutation': 'no-mutation', 'group': '5555', 'timepoint': 'D0', 'st': '42259955'}
check for base in ids == var(in this case 'C') in V1 if yes then get the count( which is 0), from ids
check for timepoints, if a time point is not in ids but in variant get the timepoint info and fill in other info from ids

Desired output

```
position    timepoint chr   st  depth   count   base    positive_strand negative_strand percent_bias    vaf
3:42259955 D0   3   42259955    224 0   C   0   0   0   0
3:42259955 C1   3   42259955    224 0   C   0   0   0   0
3:42259955 C3   3   42259955    224 0   C   0   0   0   0
3:42259955 C4   3   42259955    224 0   C   0   0   0   0
```

What i have so far

```
def getValueOf(k, L):
        #print(L)
        print(len(L))
        for i, v in enumerate(d[k] for d in L):
            return i,v
for key in ids.keys() & V1.keys():
    ## first cond compare within each list 
    if getValueOf('ref', ids[key]) == getValueOf('base', ids[key]):
       ref_count = getValueOf('count', ids[key])
       ref_depth  = getValueOf('depth', ids[key])
    ## secon cond compare between two deafultdicts
    if getValueOf('var', V1[key]) == getValueOf('base', ids[key]):
        var_count = getValueOf('count', ids[key])
```

Is there a elegant way to do this than this, should i use a defaultdict in the first place or a nested dictionary should work

## Update

#### V1

```
3:42259955 [{'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'D0', 'chrm': '3', 'st': '42259955', 'en': '42259956', 'var': 'C'}, {'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C1', 'chrm': '3', 'st': '42259955', 'en': '42259956', 'var': 'C'}, {'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C3', 'chrm': '3', 'st': '42259955', 'en': '42259956', 'var': 'C'}, {'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C4', 'chrm': '3', 'st': '42259955', 'en': '42259956', 'var': 'C'}]
```

#### ids

```
3:42259955 [{'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '141', 'base': 'A', 'count': '1', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '1', 'percent_bias': 0.0, 'vaf': 0.01, 'mutation': 'snv', 'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C4', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '141', 'base': 'C', 'count': '4', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '4', 'percent_bias': 0.0, 'vaf': 0.03, 'mutation': 'snv', 'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C4', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '141', 'base': 'G', 'count': '135', 'positive_strand': '99', 'negative_strand': '36', 'percent_bias': 0.73, 'vaf': 0.96, 'mutation': 'no-mutation', 'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C4', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '141', 'base': 'T', 'count': '1', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '1', 'percent_bias': 0.0, 'vaf': 0.01, 'mutation': 'snv', 'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C4', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '141', 'base': 'N', 'count': '0', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '0', 'percent_bias': '0', 'vaf': '0', 'mutation': 'snv', 'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C4', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '141', 'base': '+A', 'count': '1', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '1', 'percent_bias': 0.0, 'vaf': 0.01, 'mutation': 'ins', 'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C4', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '141', 'base': '+C', 'count': '13', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '13', 'percent_bias': 0.0, 'vaf': 0.09, 'mutation': 'ins', 'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C4', 'st': '42259955'}, {'chr': '3', 'ref': 'G', 'depth': '141', 'base': '+T', 'count': '11', 'positive_strand': '0', 'negative_strand': '11', 'percent_bias': 0.0, 'vaf': 0.08, 'mutation': 'ins', 'group': '555', 'timepoint': 'C4', 'st': '42259955'}]
```

#### from code

```
     position  timepoint chr ref        st depth count base positive_strand negative_strand  percent_bias   vaf
0   3:42259955      D0   3   G  42259955   141     4    C               0               4           0.0  0.03
1   3:42259955      C1   3   G  42259955   141     4    C               0               4           0.0  0.03
2   3:42259955      C3   3   G  42259955   141     4    C               0               4           0.0  0.03
3   3:42259955  C4   3   G  42259955   141     4    C               0               4           0.0  0.03
```

#### desired output

```
    position  timepoint chr ref        st depth count base positive_strand negative_strand  percent_bias   vaf
0   3:42259955      D0   3   G  42259955   141     0    C               0               0          0.0  0.00
1   3:42259955      C1   3   G  42259955   141     0    C               0               0           0.0  0.00
2   3:42259955      C3   3   G  42259955   141     0    C               0               0           0.0  0.00
3   3:42259955  C4   3   G  42259955   141     4    C               0               4           0.0  0.03
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your `ids` and `V1` actually look like still. Is the position (`3:42259955`) the key? Followed by a list of dicts as the value?

Comment: Also your `getValueOf` will only ever run one loop because you are returning. I'm not entirely sure what the point of that is?

Comment: Yes, (3:42259955) is the key getvalueof needs a yield my bad

Comment: Right, so then you'd be comparing 2 generators with your `if` statements, which will [never return true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983547/comparing-two-generators-in-python) in this situation...

Comment: Yes, I have started to sense my logic is totally wrong

Comment: Not sure if itemgetter would be ideal in this case?

Comment: It's just very muddled as to how you are intending to get to your "desired output" from the input data. It feels like you want to join the dicts from the two lists based on some conditions, but you're trying to do it across a list of dicts all in one go.

Comment: Never worked with such data structures before so I'm maxed out on ideas

Comment: My point is that I don't follow your rules for getting data from each dict in each list. Reading your example output and inputs it's not clear at all what checks you are really intending to do

Comment: well to simplify things, i think i need help with accessing the values nested in a list and apply conditions.

Comment: How you go about that will depend on how you want to use them though? If you want all the values at once then simple list comprehension can get that. If you want to iterate over them and be able to determine which value came from which dict then you'll need to do something different. As an example, your input `ids` has 5 dicts in the list but your output only has 4 rows all of which seem to correspond to the dicts in `V1`. So do you need a row per `V1` dict only?

Comment: total number of rows is dictated by 'timepoints' and 'var' in V1

Comment: So you're saying that if `base != ref` and `base == var` and `timepoint == timepoint` then merge the dictionaries? But also, if there is `base != ref` and `base == var` and the `V1` `timepoint` is not in the `ids` list, merge the `ids` dict anyway? Is it possible that a `var == ref` but that the `timepoint` from the `ids` dict is not in any of the `V1` dicts? What do you do in that situation?

Comment: yes for first condition except ids has only one time point c1 so this will be true for one one time point `timepoint == timepoint` , for second question var != ref always, and timepoint from ids will always be in V1

Comment: Are you ok to use the `pandas` library?

Comment: Sure,  anything that works however I would have loved to learn accessing nested defaultdicts, ash you are planning to use set index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I'm still not sure I've got your requirement down 100%. And it's certainly hard to know what oddities might crop up in a larger dataset, and also how inefficient this could become at scale. But I think I have solved your problem.

**UPDATED TO SOLVE THE NEW PROBLEM:**

This should be a viable solution. However at this point there are so many conditions and wrinkles, that I suspect we may be better off creating some tables using `pandas` and performing some joining and aggregating queries in terms of efficiency and simplicity of code, rather than learning how to use for loops to iterate over nested dicts.

```
def comb_dicts(ids, v1):
    fields = [
        'position', 'timepoint', 'chr', 
        'st', 'depth', 'count', 'base', 
        'positive_strand', 'negative_strand', 
        'percent_bias', 'vaf'
    ]
    def_cols = {
        'count': 0, 'positive_strand': 0, 
        'negative_strand': 0, 'percent_bias': 0.0, 'vaf': 0.0
    }
    # Make a list for our output rows
    rows = []
    # Iterate through shared keys
    for k in ids.keys() & v1.keys():
        # Empty list for our new var dicts 
        var_ds = []
        # Loop through the dicts in V1
        for d in v1[k]:
            # Find any matching dicts in the ids list - where the timepoints match
            # Use ** unpacking to create new dicts - don't update because that will alter the originals
            # Note the order of v and d, this ensures that any keys in both use the value from the V1 dict
            # This is important later
            var_ds = [
                {**v, **d, 'position': k} for v in ids[k] 
                if (
                    v['base'] != v['ref'] and 
                    d['var'] == v['base'] and 
                    d['timepoint'] == v['timepoint']
                    )
            ]
            # If we didn't find any with matching timepoints in ids then look for ones without
            # This is where the order of v and d is important. We will keep the V1 timepoint this way
            # Since this case can result in a list of dicts where some could actually be identical
            # we will need to de-dup it at some point - can do this later with pandas
            # By unpacking def_cols last we can overwrite columns that we don't want copied from ids
            if not var_ds:
                var_ds = [
                    {**v, **d, 'position': k, **def_cols} for v in ids[k] 
                    if (
                        v['base'] != v['ref'] and 
                        d['var'] == v['base']
                        )
                ]
            rows.extend(var_ds)
    return rows


my_rows = comb_dicts(ids, V1)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_rows)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df[fields]

# If you want the de-duped rows as a list of dicts then do
uniq_rows = df.to_dict('records')
```

Comment: Yes this does, i have to tweak it in many places but i got the core logic thanks

Comment: I think i did run into a bug, the count value is duplicated, what i mean is if a  base == var then get the count from id for that timepoint if the timepoint is not present the the count for that base will be zero. I have updated the question with the bug

Comment: So when I asked if you wanted to update with information from the `ids` dict even if the `timepoint` didn't match you don't actually want to do that. You want some phantom row that has only a subset of the `ids` dict extracted?

Comment: Yes, apologies i think i did not get the right df initially found this when iwas trying on the og data.

Comment: Edited with a solution